# In a T-SQL stored procedure, can optional parameters be added after an output parameter?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, optional-parameters

Let's say you have a T-SQL stored procedure with this signature:

```
myProcedure 
  @param1 varchar(10), 
  @param2 varchar(10) OUTPUT
```

Is it possible to add an optional parameter after the output parameter like this?

```
myProcedure
  @param1 varchar(10),
  @param2 varchar(10) OUTPUT, 
  @param3 varchar(10) = NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to ask a question like here because you can simply find it from internet or you can try it and find by creating a sample procedure

Any way the answer is yes you can

i have included a sample procedure for your reference

```
alter procedure proc1
@param1 nvarchar(10),
@param2  int output,
@param3 int=null

as 
begin 
select @param2
end
DECLARE @param2 int=10
EXEC proc1 @param1 = 'Calgary', @param2 = @param2 OUTPUT--will give result 10
EXEC proc1 @param1 = 'Calgary', @param2 = @param2 OUTPUT,@param3=100-- will give result 10
```